# installing libcurl4 removes R packages

Tags: curl, r

executing:

```
apt install -y libcurl4 curl
```

removes the following packages:

```
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  libblas-dev libblas3 libbz2-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libjpeg8-dev liblapack-dev liblapack3 liblzma-dev libncurses5-dev
  libreadline-dev libtinfo-dev r-cran-cluster r-doc-html
```

When I want to reinstall R then the system wants to remove libcurl4 (which is neccessary to install the lastest docker for what I know). What a vicious circle.

Anyone any advice?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1754294

Comment: Do these kinda things take long time to resolve?

Comment: I believe that there was a workaround in the end of the thread.

Comment: It is not clear to me from the havoc of comments on the page above how to resolve my specific R / libculr4 problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the various comments in the thread suggested in the comment above ([link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1754294)), there was a lot of aggressive approaches, however, one suggestion was to visit /etc/apt/sources.list and see if there is any rubish. I revisited my source.list and cleaned it up, somehow after last Ubuntu version upgrade it got messy. I made sure that the cran repository points to a mirror relevant for bionic version I got istalled and voila, it works. Cheers!