# How to install rbase without uninstalling libcurl4

Tags: uninstall, curl, r

How to install rbase without uninstalling libcurl4

I have installed Hugin. When I install rbase, hugin and libcurl4 are uninstalled. When i install Hugin, rbase and libcurl3 are uninstall.

What to do?

This is a known bug, but no solution exists...

[info here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118202/installing-libcurl4-removes-r-packages)

Is there a way to force to NOT uninstall a specific package?

Comment: According to the link you posted a fix was to check the repos in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.  I know that sometimes when you are installing an application from a different repo if it finds a version of an app that is installed it will recommend the version for removal as to not cause compatibility issues.  Try disabling 3rd party repos before trying to install rbase.

Comment: Or the very last comment in the bug stated that they removed all repos from the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder.  Maybe just try disabling before removing.

Comment: Solution came from here: A user made curl34, which you have in the same installation both curls! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061431/how-to-have-both-libcurl3-and-libcurl4-installed-at-same-time Adding ppa, and updating system was enouph for me... https://launchpad.net/~xapienz/+archive/ubuntu/curl34